# jQuery bind function from inside another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, oop, bind

I have this sample code. What I need is to run the function once on load and bind it to change event. The conditional run is required.

```
if (true) {
    Settings.customImage();
}

Settings.customImage = function() {
    var imageInput = $("#imageInput");
    var imagePreview = $('#imagePreview');

    updateCustomImage();
    imageInput.bind('change', updateCustomImage());

    function updateCustomImage() {
        var src = imageInput.val();
        alert(src);
        imagePreview.html(src ? '<img src="' + src + '">' : '');
    }
}
```

Comment: _"The conditional run is required."_ - Not for purposes of this question: it's just a pointless complication if the condition is hardcoded to `true`. @pXL - If your edit had been a suggested edit in need of review it would've been rejected as "too minor", I mean, really was that exclamation mark such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a function reference as the callback to `bind` function. In your code your are calling the function `updateCustomImage` and passing its return value (in this case `undefined`) as the `change` callback.

It should be

```
imageInput.bind('change', updateCustomImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a reference to the function

```
imageInput.bind('change', updateCustomImage);
```

or just use an anonymous function

```
imageInput.bind('change', function () {
    var src = imageInput.val();
    alert(src);
    imagePreview.html(src ? '<img src="' + src + '">' : '');
});
```